# How to listen to a raw socket and extract data in freebsd

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, freebsd

Im working in a `FreeBSD` environment. I need to listen to a raw socket (it's actually an `AF_MAP` but it's said to be based on a raw socket) and extract the information that passes through it. This socket allows a protocol/software (written in c) to communicate from user-space to kernel-space. I then need to write this information on a json file.

1) How do i listen to this socket?

2) Which utilities/programms do i need to use to monitor this socket and to retrieve the data

3) What really passes in a socket? im thinking bytes. If so, how do i  extract higher level information from the socket? Do i need to count the bytes and then convert them to higher level logic?

Im very new to sockets, so please forgive me for whole's im my logic.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use listen()
2. Suricata is pretty good for monitoring and retrieving data
3. This is a pretty good read for an intro to sockets: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

References: 
listen(): 'man listen' in command line, or http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen 
Suricata: https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/Interacting_via_Unix_Socket

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks adam, im curruntly facing a different problem in my project, as soon as i get back to this part ill let you know how it goes.